# Range of the RKKY interactions

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, magnetic-moment

I read that [RKKY interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKKY_interaction) has a longer range than just the nearest-neighbor distances. Approximately, do you know by about how long this range could be? Better, what is the longer range that has been experimentally observed?

Comment: The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RKKY_interaction) seems to fairly clearly point that it is $1/r^3$ at large distances - is there a reason that answer isn't sufficient?

Comment: "Large distances" is quite vague, I would like to see a number corresponding to the higher experimental limit of 'r'

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia page links to the [paper by Parkin and Mauri (1991)](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.44.7131) about the coupling of magnetic layers through a ruthenium spacer. The effect is seen up to 30 Å.